# Change row color depending on database value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm storing tasks in a database. Each task can be solved or open, so I created a column `isSolved` containing `true` or `false` in the DB, depending on the status.

Now I would like to display a list of all tasks and set the background color of the row for solved tasks to green and for unsolved tasks to red. But how can I realize this inside of the `.cshtml` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `@()` to do the conditional check inside a view.

```
<ul>
 @foreach(var task in Model) // Model is your list of tasks
 {
  <li class="@(task.isSolved ? "solved" : "unsolved")">@task.Description</li>
 }
<ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li.solved
{
   color: green;
}

li.unsolved
{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

add a class to each element depending on the status. Assuming you are rendering a `TaskVM` list that is in your main VM (I use `ul` tag but it works with any other tag):

```
<ul>
 @foreach(var task in Model.Tasks)
 {
  <li class="@task.Color" >text</li>
 }
<ul>
```

Your `TaskVM.Color` Property would be something like

```
public string Color
{
 get { return isSolved ? "Green" : "Red"; }
}
```

And of course you have a css rule:

```
.Green {
 background-color:#33CC00;
}
.Red {
 background-color:#FF333;
}
```